# VMFusion runScriptInGuest not working on MAC

Tags: virtual-machine, fusion, vmrun

Trying to run the following command on VMFusion professional version  10.0.1:

```
vmrun -T fusion -gu user -gp pass runScriptInGuest /Path/On/Host/\ 10.12.vmwarevm/macOS\ 10.12.vmx  /usr/bin/python /Path/On/Guest/a.py
```

Keep getting the following error:

```
Guest program exited with non-zero exit code: 1
```

Cannot find anything on this online.

Host: High-Sierra 10.13

Guest: Sierra 10.12.6

I updated the VM Tools as well.

Also, checked that the file does exists on VM and that running the script manually it does work

Any idea? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found that the problem is the fact I was trying to run the python file, which is impossible on Mac.

What you need to do is to run the actual script inline!

E.G:

```
vmrun -T fusion -gu user -gp pass runScriptInGuest /Path/On/Host/\ 10.12.vmwarevm/macOS\ 10.12.vmx  /bin/sh "/usr/bin/python -c \"`cat /Path/On/Host/To/Script`\"
```

So we will create a script on the host and cat it to the command!